# Color inverse based on dynamic background color using javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/habibillah/s3njkypt/1/)

The div background generate randomly and sometime `a` element has same colour as background colour that make `a` invisible. So, how do I make dynamically inverse the `a` background colour to ensure that `a` will never invisible?

### HTML

Login

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
....
....
```

### CSS

```
div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    $(this).css('background', color);
});
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635022/calculating-contrasting-colours-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, I thought you wanted to make `a` the same color as the background, making `a` invisible (even in between).

Comment: set anchor tag background-color:#fff to make it visible ever

Comment: @venkat7668, how if the div background is #fff?

Comment: any way you have border and color in black for the anchor tag, the case you get #fff is very rare

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the anchor in first div. Then whenever you scroll, you have to move it from one div to the next. On scroll you will check the background color of the parent div and invert the color of the anchor.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
//do stuff here
});
```

[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/s3njkypt/6/)

Comment: @Habibillah yes, you need to invert colors based on background color which is shown in alert. I have shared the logic

Comment: the alert is not show anything, except "undefined" text