# How to find optimal text color to overlay on a background color?

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I tried CSS's `mix-blend-mode: difference`, which gets close in some cases but not many cases. And then I tried the `invert-color` library which gives this:

[image]

Basically, both approaches fail at neutral colors, where the "difference" is very slight, and the inversion is barely noticeable. Instead, I would probably pick a white color depending on how dark the background is, or black otherwise. Or if it's a shade of red, I would pick maybe a shade of green or yellow that opposes it most strikingly.

Are there any algorithms for this? Can it be done in pure CSS or with some basic JS?

I am not looking for necessarily a perfect solution, as it probably depends on your eyes / the person as well, but something better than what I have so far.

Comment: Maybe this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290669/auto-contrast-font-color-to-background

Comment: This may lead to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour

Comment: That uses mix-blend-mode: difference, and the other uses invertColor, both of which I tried.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59287516/8620333

Comment: Maybe consider trying this library, or just looking at their source code to see how they do it? https://colorjs.io/docs/contrast

Comment: Yes, it's the grays that create a problem - other colors you can e.g. invert as you say. There is however a fundamental problem in your question which assumes there is an 'optimal'. There are many studies which discover different combinations are found good for reading by some people, and hopeless for others. e.g. dyslexia can be helped with various color filters.

Comment: Solved by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511606/169992

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the value of the background and you can have it as a variable you can use [`color-contrast()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-contrast)

Your code will be something like below

```
 color: color-contrast(var(--background) vs white, black)
```

The browser will either select white or black based on the background color.

Of course, it's a feature from the future as no browser support it for now: https://caniuse.com/?search=color-contrast()